# How to pass date into shell script for a sqoop command dynamically?

Tags: shell, hadoop

Im working on a sqoop import with the following command:

```
#!/bin/bash
    while IFS=":" read -r server dbname table; do
    sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://$server/$dbname --username root --password cloudera --table mydata --hive-import --hive-table dynpart --check-column id --last-value $(hive -e "select max(id) from dynpart"); --hive-partition-key 'thisday' --hive-partition-value '01-01-2016'
done<tables.txt
```

Im doing the partition for everyday.
Hive table:

```
create table dynpart(id int, name char(30), city char(30))
  partitioned by(thisday char(10))
  row format delimited
  fields terminated by ','
  stored as textfile
  location '/hive/mytables'
  tblproperties("comment"="partition column: thisday structure is dd-mm-yyyy");
```

But I don't want to give the partition value directly as I want to create a sqoop job and run it everyday. In the script, how can I pass the date value to sqoop command dynamically (format: dd/mm/yyyy) instead of giving it directly ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD (!!)

Comment: Well, Im getting the date in the desired format. And I have the data in table in 3 columns. The problem is, the actual data from the table is coming as NULL like below
NULL NULL NULL 30-03-2017

Answer (score 0):

you can use the shell command date to get it (ubuntu 14.04):

```
$ date +%d/%m/%Y
22/03/2017
```

Comment: I gave format as you mentioned but I get the output as 
NULL NULL NULL +%d/%m/%Y

Answer (score 0):

You Can try the below  Code

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%d-%m-%y")
while IFS=":" read -r server dbname table; do
sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://$server/$dbname --username root --password cloudera --table mydata --hive-import --hive-table dynpart --check-column id --last-value $(hive -e "select max(id) from dynpart"); --hive-partition-key 'thisday' --hive-partition-value $DATE
done<tables.txt
```

**Hope this Helps**

Comment: Im getting the date but the other column data is coming NULL like
NULL NULL NULL 22-03-2017
My RDBMS table has a record like 1 Abcd NewYork

Comment: do you have data for that date partition?....22-03-2017?  from  the above query us are extracting for 01-01-2016 why dont you set DATE variable as DATE="01-01-2016"

Comment: I tried as you said by giving the date directly.
#!/bin/bash
DATE="22-03-2017"
while IFS=":" read -r server dbname tablename; do
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://$server/$dbname --table $tablename --username root --password cloudera --hive-import --hive-table dynpart --hive-partition-key 'thisday' --hive-partition-value $DATE --target-dir '/user/hive/newimp5' -m 1
done<tables.txt

Im getting data like this:
NULL NULL NULL 22-03-2017

I do have data in mysql table: only 1 record.
 1  Sidhartha  Noida