# How to use insert statement for a Hive partitioned table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive table dynpart.

```
id                      int                                 
name                    char(30)                                    
city                    char(30)                                    
thisday                 string                                      

# Partition Information      
# col_name              data_type               comment                      
thisday                 string
```

It is partitioned by 'thisday' whose datatype is STRING.
How can I insert a single record into the table in a particular partition. I know there is load command to load an entire file data into hive table. I just want to know how an Insert statement can be written for a partitioned table. I tried to write command like below but this is taking data from another table.

```
insert into droplater partition(thisday='30/03/2017') select * from dynpart;
```

The table: Droplater has the same structure as dynpart. But the above command is to insert the data from another table. What I'd like to learn is to write a simple insert command into a partition, like: `insert into tabname values(1,"abcd","efgh");`into the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for primitive types only (no arrays, structs etc.)

```
insert into tabname partition (thisday='30/03/2017') values (1,"abcd","efgh");
```

This will work for all types

```
insert into tabname partition (thisday='30/03/2017') select 1,"abcd","efgh";
```

P.s.

By all means, partition your table by date (`(thisday date)` )

```
insert into tabname partition (thisday=date '2017-03-30') ...
```

or at least use the ISO date format

```
insert into tabname partition (thisday='2017-03-30') ...
```

Comment: I understood the concept now and your query is working.

Comment: About the 'date' format for partition, I'm trying to execute a dynamic sqoop partition by passing the date from Shell Script. Hoping you'd like to take a look at it.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945763/how-to-pass-date-into-shell-script-for-a-sqoop-command-dynamically)